# Unset variable specific key from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have different multidimensional arrays with different keys and values:

```
$array_1 = array('cars' => array('audi' => array('a3' => array('one', 'two', 'three'), 'a5' => array('five', 'six', 'seven')), 'mercedes' => array('type_1' => array('submodel' => array('whatever'))), 'other_cat' => array('different_things')));
```

then I would like to unset a specific key, for example:

```
unset($array_1['cars']['audi']['a5']);
```

Now I like to "split it up", to have the key variable.

```
$to_unset = ['cars']['audi']['a5'];
```

How can I unset that specific (variable!) key?

Aäron

Comment: What do you mean by `to have the key variable`?

Comment: unset($array_1.$to_unset); //unset the $to_unset from $array_1 ...

Comment: The assignment `$to_unset = ['cars']['audi']['a5'];` is not quite what you want. It is valid PHP code but it evaluates to `NULL` (and triggers a notice about the `'audi'` index not existing in the `['cars']` array). You should start by designing a way to define the list of keys you need to reach the item to unset.

Comment: What I want to do is to unset a multidimensional array from another multidimensional array, in this case it's ['cars']['audi']['a5'] but it also could be ['song']['a5'] or ['cars']['mercedes']['cars'], just matching on "a5" is not a solution in my case. Thanks for your help already

Comment: I've attempted to answer your question. Please let me know if there is anything unclear or if I did not fully answer it.

Comment: I have fixed the issue you had with my code, forgot to reference the objects that, because I was simply editing a variable without it's reference to the array outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy utility to avoid removing array keys that do not exist by accident:

```
function removeArrayKey($path, &$array ) {

    $array_temp = &$array;
    $previousItem = null;

    $path_bits = explode( ".", $path );

        foreach( $path_bits as &$path_bit ) {

           if( !isset( $array_temp[ $path_bit ] ) ) {
                  die("Error" . $path_bit);
                   //throw new Exception( "Path does not exist in array" );
            }

            $previousItem = &$array_temp;
            $array_temp = &$array_temp[ $path_bit ];

        }

        if( isset( $previousItem ) ) {

             unset( $previousItem[ $path_bit ] );

        }

        return $array;

}
```

To use the function, simply use `removeArrayKey( "cars.mercedes.cars", $array_1 );` and separate each array index with a `.`

Comment: This only works if the first key is cars or mercedes but not with multidimensional arrays, thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: It does? Simply change "cars.mercedes.cars" to "cars.audi" or whatever else you want... Please read my explanation carefully.

Comment: And what are you trying to say with that reply?

Comment: Comment box is to short, check my answer above in the question

Comment: I have fixed the issue.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

So as i see your problem, you'd like to save your array path into a variable. You can solve this problem on two different ways:

### Save every key into a variable

The way i would do it, if my array structure looks always the same (e.g. [cars][type][model]). You can save the key to delete into a variable:

```
$cars = 'cars';
$type = 'audi';
$model = 'a5';

unset($array_1[$cars][$type][$model]);
```

This will work excellent in a for(each) loop.

### Saving your keys into an array

This method will save your problem, but it is not the best option. You can save all the keys you like to unset into an array. This way can cause many bugs and you should reconsider your array structure, if this way is your solution.

```
// arrays start at 0
$to_unset = [
    0 => 'cars',
    1 => 'audi',
    2 => 'a5',
];

unset($array_1[$to_unset[0]][$to_unset[1]][$to_unset[2]]);
```

An other possible option here is to name the keys of the $to_unset array.

```
// arrays start at 0
$to_unset = [
    'cars' => 'cars',
    'type' => 'audi',
    'model' => 'a5',
];

unset($array_1[$to_unset['cars']][$to_unset['type']][$to_unset['model']]);
```

Comment: This is a possible solution if you know the keys in advance, but that's not the case. Thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can probably go with [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but it's **not recommended**.

```
eval('unset($array_1' . $to_unset . ');');
```

Comment: This really seems the only solution, it works! thanks a lot

Comment: As you said, do NOT use this unless you know 100% sure that the input is not malicious.